# Is it possible to use OBS virtual camera on NOX or Blustack?

Tags: android-camera

Some apps require live streaming on mobile phones. I'm looking to get around the law through OBS and NOX or Blustack

Comment: This isn't a programming question, and so [does not belong on this particular Stackexchange site](/on-topic). You may want to ask this on https://superuser.com instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.